# Weird CSS/Nav Blank Space

Tags: css, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, uinavigationbar

Hello stack overflow community we meet again. I create this two leveled Navigation bar with CSS and i got everything to work but for one little issue, there a blank space that i can't seem to get rid of

Here is the Html

```
<ul id="nav-top">
        <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.asp">Join TGA</a></li>
    </ul>

    <img src="wp-content/themes/tga/pictures/topbanner.jpg" id="top-banner" />
    <div id="header">
    <ul id="nav-bottom">
            <li><a href="#">Percoidei</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Remoras</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tilefishes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bluefishes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tigerfishes</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Anabantoidei</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Climbing perches</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Labyrinthfishes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kissing gouramis</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pike-heads</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Giant gouramis</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

And here is the CSS

```
#nav-bottom{
    list-style-type:none;
    height: 34px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-image: url(pictures/nav-graphic.png);
    line-height: 2;
}

#nav-bottom li:hover {
    list-style-type:none;
    height: 34px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    line-height: 2;
    background-color: #494949;
    color: white;
}

#nav-bottom li{
    float:left;
}

#nav-bottom a{
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}



#nav-bottom li ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10em;
    left: -999em;
    list-style-type:none;
    background-color: #494949;
    color: white;
}


#nav-bottom li ul li a {
    color: white;
    width: 10em;
    border-bottom:1px solid white;
}

#nav-bottom li ul li a:hover {
    color: white;
    width: 10em;
    background-color: #2a2a2a;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom:1px solid white;
}

#nav-bottom li:hover ul {
    left: auto;
}
```

Here is what it looks like

look at link bellow  (sorry don't have the rep points to upload the picture)

What am i doing wrong that causing that blank space?

---

Ok here is the blank space i'm talking about
http://i52.tinypic.com/dcsg9j.png

And I uploaded it to jsfiddle (cool dev site love it) and it works fine in there, do you think is a problem with my browser (chrome 14.0.835.163 running on mac) it also does the blank space in firefox?
http://jsfiddle.net/donvito101/ZWeVq/

Comment: Thomas, can you point out which space you consider to be blank? A lot of that space could be considered blank :)

You should also try using Firebug in Firefox, or the web inspector built into Chrome and Safari. You can view the computed styles of each element and hopefully get an idea where the space is coming from.

Comment: A bit off topic, but I'd change the text color on your menu when the mouse rolls over. Black on dark gray doesn't look too good ;)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean that blank space that indents the submenu ?
In this case it's propably because you are starting a new  in the submenu, which is always indented. Put a few px negative padding (or margin?) for #nav-bottom ul and you should be good! e.g.

```
#nav-bottom ul { padding-left: -15px; }
```

Comment: Thanks! but I tried your theory of either using padding-left or margin-left and either is did nothing or it did this http://i53.tinypic.com/5xsk1z.png

Comment: I think we are on the right way with this though. Try either #nav-bottom li ul li a {padding-left:-15px;} OR give the submenu links or list-points (<li>) a seperate class/id and give them the negative padding/margin. I personally would prefer the latter, just to keep the whole css-code a bit cleaner.